broken server folder permissions after renaming remote pc user account
I have a couple of Windows 10 user's PCs with local users accounts named "admin". PCs were added to a workgroup with file server. So I renamed user accounts to uniqe ones using computer management, configured server user accounts with the same names and passwords and configured shared folder permissions for users. Nevertheless remote users can't access to server folders until server folders has "admin" account privileges. Strange though.
How can I fix the remote account to match the local account of the same name?

If they are local accounts, then they might have been using saved credentials (e.g. because the local and server passwords didn't match). Open the Windows "Credential Manager" app to check whether any username/password is saved – or use cmdkey /list for the same. After removing any unwanted entries, reboot the client.
Also, if I remember correctly, credentials could be saved as part of a drive mapping; so if the client systems access the server through a mapped drive, try removing and re-creating it.

Client indeed had saved credentials. Cleaning credentials manager solved the problem.
